# extJs toolbar that take only nessassary size

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want toolbar to take only nessasary \ auto size.. how can i do that?

```
MyViewportUi = Ext.extend(Ext.Viewport, {
layout: 'fit',
initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'My Panel',
            layout: 'vbox',
            tbar: {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'MyButton 1'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'MyButton 2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ];
    MyViewportUi.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a toolbar is just that, a bar, it will expand to fill all available space. Buttons placed inside a toolbar will occupy as much space as they need, but the toolbar will still expand to fill the maximum width possible.

The [`Ext.Toolbar`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Toolbar) has a property called `autoWidth`, but this will only cause the toolbar to use the css `width: auto` property. This is not perfect, but it's probably your best bet.

Comment: I tried autoWidth property.. it dosen't work.. but anyway i agree with you, it's a weird to use standart controls in "non standart" way :)

Comment: Hmm, well, then I suspect it's not possible other than setting the width of the toolbar, which I suspect you do not want to do. What sort of behaviour are you looking for anyway?

Comment: I want create toolbar (inside of a panel, or anyway) that will take ONLY size that nessasary...